# Cocoa Auto Layout Visual Format: Align views without setting space constraints

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, visual-format-language

I try to implement the following constraints with Auto Layout Visual Format:

1. Standard distance from **container view** to **label**
2. Fixed distance from **container view** to **textField**
3. Baseline alignment between **label** and **textField**

The first two constraints are straightforward:

```
var viewDict: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]
viewDict["label"] = label
viewDict["textField"] = textField

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[label]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-100-[textField]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
```

To align two views I understand I have to set the options parameter accordingly.
According to the spec, the options parameter applies to the views stated in the format string parameter.

But how do I list views in the format string without making assumptions regarding the space between the views?

If I do something like this I create an unwanted constraint regarding the distance between `label` and `textField`:

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[label]-[inputField]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
```

I guess I could work around it by setting the priority of the unnecessary size constraint to zero, but still I have the feeling I'm missing something conceptually here.

Is it advisable not to use Visual Format in such a scenario?

Comment: There's plenty of stuff that the visual format language can't do. It's not the best tool for all jobs. This seems like a task that it's not well suited for. Just create the constraint using `+[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:...]`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer doesn't come as a surprise. I just thought, since it seems such a basic use case to me, that I was missing something fundamental...

Comment: You can specify something like `"[label]-(>=0)-[inputField]"`, but the best way to do this is just to create a constraint for the baseline.